# UPDATE INNER JOIN with COALESCE returning different results than analogous SELECT query

Tags: mysql

I'm seeing behavior I can't explain when using a COALESCE within an INNER JOIN clause in an UPDATE statement. The analogous SELECT statement works.

MySQL v5.7.27. (I have to stay on 5.7.x for AWS Aurora MySQL compatibility.)

Schema and data:

```
CREATE TABLE S1( id bigint not null, 
displayName varchar(255) not null collate utf8_general_ci );

CREATE TABLE PI( S1_id bigint null, 
col1 varchar(255) null collate utf8_general_ci, 
col2 varchar(255) null collate utf8_general_ci);

INSERT INTO S1 (id, displayName)
VALUES( 1, 'test');

INSERT INTO PI (S1_id, col1, col2)
VALUES( null, null, 'test' );
```

Working select query:

```
select S1.id, S1.displayName, COALESCE( PI.col1, PI.col2)
FROM PI 
  INNER JOIN S1 
  ON S1.displayName = COALESCE(PI.col1, PI.col2) collate utf8_unicode_ci;
```

returns 1 row:

```
id displayName COALESCE( PI.col1, PI.col2)
1  test        test
```

I'm expecting this update statement to update 1 row:

```
UPDATE PI
INNER JOIN S1 
  ON COALESCE( PI.col1, PI.col2 ) collate utf8_unicode_ci = S1.displayName
SET PI.S1_id = S1.id;

Expected: 1 row updated in PI, S1_id = 1
Actual: 0 rows updated
```

For grins, I also removed the COLLATE since it's technically not required:

```
UPDATE PI
INNER JOIN S1 ON COALESCE( PI.col1, PI.col2 ) = S1.displayName
SET PI.S1_id = S1.id;

Expected: 1 row updated in PI, S1_id = 1
Actual: 0 rows updated
```

and also swapped the ON clause:

```
UPDATE PI
INNER JOIN S1 ON S1.displayName = COALESCE( PI.col1, PI.col2 )
SET PI.S1_id = S1.id;

Expected: 1 row updated in PI, S1_id = 1
Actual: 0 rows updated
```

I'm able to get around this by adding a column to PI and precalculating the COALESCE value, but I'm extremely curious what's going on!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue.https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aPNK4Dfzjx8wHwS5Ahqzix/0

Answer (score 0):

in this query it seems that the join is not done against s1.displayName

```
UPDATE PI
INNER JOIN S1 
  ON COALESCE( PI.col1, PI.col2 ) collate utf8_unicode_ci = S1.displayName
SET PI.S1_id = S1.id;
```